# Migrating several branches to another Gitlab project

Tags: git, migration, gitlab

We've got a long-running Gitlab project (with accompanying git repository) that is now close to its finish.

This repository has about 400 branches.

I want to migrate some of those branches (2-5) to another project with another git repo and use them as a starting point.

What is the best way to do it?

I've read manuals for `git clone --single-branch` and `git clone --branch` but it is still not clear how this can help me when I've got more than one branch.

I could clone single branch from that repository, change remote and push.
Then, how can I add another single branch?

Gitlab is CE, version 11.0.2, installed from Omnibus package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've managed to do it

1. Create a new empty repository
2. Add it to the old one as a new remote
3. For all desired branches: `git push new_remote refs/heads/branch:refs/heads/branch`
4. Clone new repo, make modifications according to a new project's tasks.